How to implement virtual horizontal scroll for the Antd table?
I am experiencing performance issues with an Ant Design (Antd) table containing more than 200 columns. You can preview the problem here: Antd Table. AntD supports vertical virtual scrolling, but not horizontal scrolling.
I found a related discussion on the Antd GitHub: Issue #48331. It mentions that having more than 50 columns in a table is generally considered an unreasonable design.
Therefore, I need to implement virtual scrolling for both horizontal directions myself. I came across an example of a table with both horizontal and vertical virtual scrolling: Grid Gutters.
How can I implement that kind of virtual horizontal scrolling for an AntD table?
